Four plots are not combining in one frame using Mathematica 11.0 . Show command isn't evaluating them to be in one frame. Why?
I want to combine my graphs in one frame. I have used the Show command on Mathematica 11.0 several times but it always responds, "Could not combine the graphics object in Show." Elsewise, my graphs are perfectly drawn but couldn't be combined. Four different graphs have been evaluated, applying different boundary conditions. It's actually my research work and I am being stuck with it for many days and don't know what the problem is. Same problem is with the other 4 codes. Graphs have been drawn but couldn't combine. I have to submit my work in few days. Kindly, address my problem asap and guide me what measures can be taken. I am attaching the code below as well.
Code:
Da = 0.7;
Rd = 0.2;
M = 0.4; 
m = 0.1;
γ = 1;
B1 = 0.3;
B2 = 0.03;
Nt = 0.1;
Nb = 1;
Pr = 5;
a = 0.3;
b = 0.1;
x = 0.2;
t = 0.1;
ϕ = 0.1;
F = 1;
h1 = -1 - m*x - a*Cos[π*(x - t) + ϕ]*Sin[π*(x - t) + ϕ];
h2 = 1 + m*x + b*Cos[π*(x - t)]*Sin[π*(x - t)];
EQ1[Br_] = (1 + Rd*Pr)*θ''[y] + Br *(ψ''[y])^2 + Nb*Pr*σ'[y]*θ'[y] + Nt*Pr*(θ'[y])^2;
EQ2[Br_] = σ''[y] + (Nt/Nb)*θ''[y];
EQ3[Br_] = ψ''''[y] - (M^2 + 1/Da)*(ψ''[y]);
BC1[Br_] = ((ψ[y] + F/2) /. y -> h1);
BC2[Br_] = ((ψ'[y] - γ*ψ''[y]) /. y -> h1);
BC3[Br_] = ((ψ[y] - F/2) /. y -> h2);
BC4[Br_] = ((ψ'[y] + γ*ψ''[y]) /. y -> h2);
BC5[Br_] = ((θ'[y] - B1*θ[y]) /. y -> h1);
BC6[Br_] = ((σ'[y] - B2*σ[y]) /. y -> h1);
BC7[Br_] = ((θ'[y] - B1*(1 - θ[y])) /. y -> h2);
BC8[Br_] = ((σ'[y] - B2*(1 - σ[y])) /. y -> h2);
S1 = NDSolve[{EQ1[0] == 0, EQ2[0] == 0, EQ3[0] == 0, BC1[0] == 0, 
    BC2[0] == 0, BC3[0] == 0, BC4[0] == 0, BC5[0] == 0, BC6[0] == 0, 
    BC7[0] == 0, BC8[0] == 0}, {ψ, θ, σ}, {y, h1, 
    h2}];
B1 = Plot[Evaluate[D[ψ[y], y] /. S1], {y, h1, h2} , 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}, 
  AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"u\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]


S2 = NDSolve[{EQ1[0.01] == 0, EQ2[0.01] == 0, EQ3[0.01] == 0, 
    BC1[0.01] == 0, BC2[0.01] == 0, BC3[0.01] == 0, BC4[0.01] == 0, 
    BC5[0.01] == 0, BC6[0.01] == 0, BC7[0.01] == 0, 
    BC8[0.01] == 0}, {ψ, θ, σ}, {y, h1, h2}];
B2 = Plot[Evaluate[D[ψ[y], y] /. S2], {y, h1, h2} , 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004], Dashed}, 
  AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"u\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]


S3 = NDSolve[{EQ1[0.02] == 0, EQ2[0.02] == 0, EQ3[0.02] == 0, 
    BC1[0.02] == 0, BC2[0.02] == 0, BC3[0.02] == 0, BC4[0.02] == 0, 
    BC5[0.02] == 0, BC6[0.02] == 0, BC7[0.02] == 0, 
    BC8[0.02] == 0}, {ψ, θ, σ}, {y, h1, h2}];
B3 = Plot[Evaluate[D[ψ[y], y] /. S3], {y, h1, h2} , 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashing [Small], Thickness[0.004]}, 
  AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"u\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]


S4 = NDSolve[{EQ1[0.03] == 0, EQ2[0.03] == 0, EQ3[0.03] == 0, 
    BC1[0.03] == 0, BC2[0.03] == 0, BC3[0.03] == 0, BC4[0.03] == 0, 
    BC5[0.03] == 0, BC6[0.03] == 0, BC7[0.03] == 0, 
    BC8[0.03] == 0}, {ψ, θ, σ}, {y, h1, h2}];
B4 = Plot[Evaluate[D[ψ[y], y] /. S4], {y, h1, h2} , 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black, DotDashed, Thickness[0.004]},
   AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"u\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]


Show[{B1, B2, B3, B4}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 16}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"u\",\nFontSize->18,\nFontWeight->\"Plain\",\n\
FontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]


Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Please edit the question and include your Mathematica code.

Your four plots are combined in a single frame. I don't see what is needed in this question?
